# How to make array non zero based in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Im trying to create a d3.js graph from a rails database. This takes the following json

```
    {  
   "nodes":[  
      {  
         "name":"Sebo",
         "group":4,
         "id":1
      },
      {  
         "name":"Pierre",
         "group":5,
         "id":2
      },
      {  
         "name":"Bilbo",
         "group":2,
         "id":3
      },
      {  
         "name":"yyyyyyyy",
         "group":2,
         "id":4
      }
   ],
   "links":[  
      {  
         "source":3,
         "target":2,
         "value":null
      },
      {  
         "source":3,
         "target":1,
         "value":null
      },
      {  
         "source":4,
         "target":2,
         "value":null
      },
      {  
         "source":4,
         "target":1,
         "value":null
      }
   ]
}
```

I have created a button that allows a current user to follow another user. This then gets stored in a database and eventually the graph can be re-visualised.

The problem is that the request to update the database is based on the current user id (from the database). This is a non-zero based indexing so the first user is user id:1. However the json uses zero based indexing. This means that if user_id=1 connects to user_id=4 then when the graph is seen again this connection is attributed to user_id:2. What would be great is if I could specify that the user_id index could start with zero so that the array and database are in agreement. Is this the correct way to think about this? Can I force the indexing of the user table to start at zero eg in a rails schema?

Comment: You know that you won't have sequential ids in your database, right? The moment you delete even **once** user with id `2`, that id won't be available anymore, meaning that you'll have `1`, `3`, `4` and you array will be broken from there on. You need to find a different solution on d3js, but I don't know the correct way to handle these situations because I'm not experienced with it.

Comment: Its a very good point. For the moment Ill use the id's but am going to change up to a unique node name so should be ok in the end

Comment: You could add a separate field to reference against and just have logic to assign it yourself (probably in the model's initialize method).  Then you don't care what the database does because you'll just search against your custom field as if it were the primary id field.   Is that you meant by a "unique node name"?

Comment: Having the database update rely upon what index the data has in a JSON array sounds rather fragile to me. Why do you need to do it that way?

Comment: Basically the forced directed graph I'm using uses json so at the moment I dont have a choice. So I guess the answer is that I can't either use zero based database table indexing or 1-based arrays?